# extracting p values from multiple linear regression (lm) inside of a ddply function using spatial data

Tags: r, plyr, lm

I have a set of spatial coordinate (x,y) data that has a response variable for each coordinate over the course of several years. The following code generates a similar data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:2, 2),
  x = rep(c(25, 30),10),
  y = rep(c(100, 200), 10),
  year = rep(1980:1989, 2),
  response = rnorm(20)
)
```

The resulting data frame:

```
head(df)

 id  x   y year   response
1  1 25 100 1980  0.1707431
2  2 30 200 1981  1.3562263
3  1 25 100 1982 -0.4590506
4  2 30 200 1983  1.3238410
5  1 25 100 1984  1.7765772
6  2 30 200 1985 -0.6258069
```

I want to run a linear regression on each cell through time to get the change in response variable. To do this, I use plyr and the ddply command:

```
require(plyr)    
lm.df <- ddply(df, .(id), function(z)coef(lm(response ~ year, data = z)))
```

Then I recombine w/ the spatial data (the example here of the recombination is a bit simple, but works for the example.):

```
points <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2),
  x = c(25,30),
  y = c(100,200)
)

lm.stack <-  merge(points, lm.df, by="id")
colnames(lm.stack) <- c("ID", "x", "y", "intercept", "slope")

print(lm.stack)
ID  x   y intercept       slope
1  1 25 100  257.7291 -0.12985632
2  2 30 200  173.3676 -0.08708068
```

This works great. But what I want, is to be able to extract the adj r squared value of each lm model to be able to denote significant trends by coordinate cell w/ the ultimate goal of projecting a map of cells colored by significance value. This is where I need help and am greatly appreciative. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest a combination of packages `dplyr` and `broom`.
This approach will return everything you need to know about the model (info about coefficients and info about model itself) as a dataframe:

```
set.seed(25)

df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:2, 2),
  x = rep(c(25, 30),10),
  y = rep(c(100, 200), 10),
  year = rep(1980:1989, 2),
  response = rnorm(20)
)

df

#    id  x   y year    response
# 1   1 25 100 1980 -0.21183360
# 2   2 30 200 1981 -1.04159113
# 3   1 25 100 1982 -1.15330756
# 4   2 30 200 1983  0.32153150
# 5   1 25 100 1984 -1.50012988
# 6   2 30 200 1985 -0.44553326
# 7   1 25 100 1986  1.73404543
# 8   2 30 200 1987  0.51129562
# 9   1 25 100 1988  0.09964504
# 10  2 30 200 1989 -0.05789111
# 11  1 25 100 1980 -1.74278763
# 12  2 30 200 1981 -1.32495298
# 13  1 25 100 1982 -0.54793388
# 14  2 30 200 1983 -1.45638428
# 15  1 25 100 1984  0.08268682
# 16  2 30 200 1985  0.92757895
# 17  1 25 100 1986 -0.71676933
# 18  2 30 200 1987  0.96239968
# 19  1 25 100 1988  1.54588458
# 20  2 30 200 1989 -1.00976361



library(dplyr)
library(broom)


df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  do({model = lm(response~year, data=.)    # create your model
      data.frame(tidy(model),              # get coefficient info
                 glance(model))})          # get model info


#   id        term     estimate    std.error statistic    p.value r.squared adj.r.squared     sigma statistic.1  p.value.1 df    logLik      AIC      BIC deviance df.residual
# 1  1 (Intercept) -492.2144842 213.19252113 -2.308779 0.04978386 0.3996362    0.32459069 0.9611139    5.325253 0.04987162  2 -12.67704 31.35409 32.26184 7.389919           8
# 2  1        year    0.2479705   0.10745580  2.307651 0.04987162 0.3996362    0.32459069 0.9611139    5.325253 0.04987162  2 -12.67704 31.35409 32.26184 7.389919           8
# 3  2 (Intercept) -258.6253012 196.88284243 -1.313600 0.22539989 0.1771294    0.07427055 0.8871395    1.722063 0.22582607  2 -11.87614 29.75227 30.66003 6.296132           8
# 4  2        year    0.1301582   0.09918521  1.312274 0.22582607 0.1771294    0.07427055 0.8871395    1.722063 0.22582607  2 -11.87614 29.75227 30.66003 6.296132           8
```

You can use `group_by(id,x,y)` if you really want your x and y columns in your final dataframe. For example if you want a similar output to the one you provided you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)

dd = 
    df %>% 
      group_by(id, x, y) %>%
      do({model = lm(response~year, data=.)    # create your model
      data.frame(tidy(model),              # get coefficient info
                 glance(model))})          # get model info
```

Then select the info you need:

```
 dd %>%
  select(id, x, y, term, estimate, adj.r.squared)

#   id  x   y        term     estimate adj.r.squared
# 1  1 25 100 (Intercept) -492.2144842    0.32459069
# 2  1 25 100        year    0.2479705    0.32459069
# 3  2 30 200 (Intercept) -258.6253012    0.07427055
# 4  2 30 200        year    0.1301582    0.07427055
```

where you get one row for the intercept and one row for the slope.

Or, even reshape that data frame to:

```
dd %>%
  select(id, x, y, term, estimate, adj.r.squared) %>%
  spread(term, estimate)

#   id  x   y adj.r.squared (Intercept)      year
# 1  1 25 100    0.32459069   -492.2145 0.2479705
# 2  2 30 200    0.07427055   -258.6253 0.1301582
```

column `year` is the `slope` (coefficient of variable `year`)

In a similar way you can also use package `purrr` to create a new data frame that has list columns with the corresponding info:

```
set.seed(25)

df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:2, 2),
  x = rep(c(25, 30),10),
  y = rep(c(100, 200), 10),
  year = rep(1980:1989, 2),
  response = rnorm(20)
)

library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

dd = df %>%
  group_by(id, x, y) %>%                                  # for each combination of those variables
  nest() %>%                                              # nest data (rest of columns)
  mutate(Model = map(data, ~lm(response~year, data=.)),   # use nested data to build model of interest
         Coeff_Info = map(Model, tidy),                   # get coefficient info
         Model_Info = map(Model, glance)) %>%             # get model info
  ungroup()                                               # forget the grouping

# check how new dataset looks like
dd

# # A tibble: 2 x 7
#        id     x     y              data    Model           Coeff_Info            Model_Info
#     <int> <dbl> <dbl>            <list>   <list>               <list>                <list>
#   1     1    25   100 <tibble [10 x 2]> <S3: lm> <data.frame [2 x 5]> <data.frame [1 x 11]>
#   2     2    30   200 <tibble [10 x 2]> <S3: lm> <data.frame [2 x 5]> <data.frame [1 x 11]>
```

You can still access any element you want, but remember that some of your columns now have list elements:

```
# get coefficient info for both models
dd$Coeff_Info

# [[1]]
#          term     estimate   std.error statistic    p.value
# 1 (Intercept) -492.2144842 213.1925211 -2.308779 0.04978386
# 2        year    0.2479705   0.1074558  2.307651 0.04987162
# 
# [[2]]
#          term     estimate    std.error statistic   p.value
# 1 (Intercept) -258.6253012 196.88284243 -1.313600 0.2253999
# 2        year    0.1301582   0.09918521  1.312274 0.2258261


# get the r squared value for 1st model
dd %>%                    # from new dataset
  filter(id == 1) %>%     # keep all info / rows of 1st model
  pull(Model_Info) %>%    # get model info
  map_dbl("r.squared")    # show r squared

# [1] 0.3996362
```

Or, alternatively

```
dd %>%                        # from new dataset
  unnest(id, Model_Info) %>%  # umnest id and model info
  filter(id == 1) %>%         # keep row of 1st model
  pull(r.squared)             # show the r squared

# [1] 0.3996362
```

Comment: This may work, but I am trying to learn pipes quickly to see how to do it. The ultimate result needs to be in a data frame similar to what I have above, how do I get there?

Comment: But the final output is a dataframe. You can pick anything you want from there and do whatever you need to do. The advantage is that you can combine info instead of extracting just coefficients, or just adj R squared. I will update my answer to extract only what you mentioned.

Comment: do function is interesting. Can you rewrite with map?

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the models in a list, then you can easily extract whatever you want from them using `lapply` or any of the other list traversal functions.

```
lms <- dlply(df, .(id), function(x) lm(response ~ year, data=x))
rsq <- lapply(lms, function(x) summary(x)$adj.r.squared)  # get the adjusted r2
```

An alternative to making the list yourself, is `lmList` from `nlme`

```
library(nlme)
lms2 <- lmList(response ~ year | id, data=df)
summary(lms2)$adj.r.squared
```

Comment: This works quite well. My follow-up, since I have notoriously avoided lists, is how would I move this to a data frame similar to the lm.stack one in the example where the final two columns are the adj r squared and say p-value?

Comment: @Jeff just assign the result to a columnin your data.frame