# Converting code from ddply to plyr in R

Tags: r, plyr

I want to change a bit of my code to use plyr instead of ddply because I think it will be faster on my large (>1e6) data set. Here is an example data set:

```
ID <- rep(1:3, each=6)
Row <- rep(1, each=18) 
Col <- rep(rep(1:2, each=3), times=3)
Meas <- rnorm(18,3,1)
len <- rep(1:3, times=6)

df <- data.frame(ID, Row, Col, Meas, len)
```

The code I normally use is this:

```
res <- ddply(df, c("ID", "Row", "Col"), function(x) coefficients(lm(Meas~len,x)))
```

It performs a lm for Meas against len for each subset of df by ID, Row and Col, extracting the coefficients. On my large data set it takes 30 seconds (not the end of the world, I know). When I try plyr with this:

```
res2 <- df %>% group_by("ID", "Row", "Col") %>% (function(x) coefficients(lm(Meas~len,x))) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

I only get one intercept and grad. I've read this ([extracting p values from multiple linear regression (lm) inside of a ddply function using spatial data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274779/extracting-p-values-from-multiple-linear-regression-lm-inside-of-a-ddply-funct)) which gave me this attempt:

```
res3 <- df %>% group_by("ID", "Row", "Col") %>%
  do({model=lm(Meas~len, data=.)
  data.frame(tidy(model),
             glance(model))})
```

But again no luck. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

**Update:**

Out of interest for anyone running a similar thing on large data sets:

```
system.time(
lres <- ddply(I, c("ERF", "Wafer", "Row", "Col"), function(x) coefficients(lm(Rds.on.fwd~Length,x)))
)

user  system elapsed 
  25.80    0.06   26.02

system.time(
  lres2 <- I %>% group_by(ERF, Wafer, Row, Col) %>% do(
    as.data.frame.list(coef(lm(Rds.on.fwd~Length, data=.))))
  )

user  system elapsed 
  43.12    0.25   44.02 

system.time(
lres3 <- setDT(I)[, as.list(coef(lm(Rds.on.fwd~Length))), .(ERF,Wafer, Row, Col)]
)

user  system elapsed 
  19.77    0.05   19.91
```

so actually @akrun the data.table option is the best so thank you again.

Comment: Tru `df %>% group_by(ID, Row, Col) %>% do(as.data.frame.list(coef(lm(Meas~len, data=.))))`

Comment: Lovely, thank you. So can I just confirm what "do" does and why I need ".list".

Comment: In fact google will tell me, no need to worry. Thanks again.

Comment: If you just do `as.data.frame` or `data.frame`, it will be a single column that have both the intercept and slope `rbind` together.

Comment: Also have a look at the `broom` package. This can extract the relevant information from `lm` for you.

Comment: For future readers, I want to point out not to miss that taking the quotations marks off  in the plyr version is important. They are not being used as strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We modify the OP's last piece of code to get the expected output.  We group by the variables 'ID', 'Row' and 'Col', `do` the `lm` using the variables 'Meas' and 'len', extract the coefficients with `coef`, convert it to a `list` and then to `data.frame` (`as.data.frame.list`) to create two new columns ('intercept' and 'slope').

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Row, Col) %>%
  do(as.data.frame.list(coef(lm(Meas~len, data=.))))
```

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table, group by 'ID', 'Row', and 'Col', do the `lm`, extract the coefficients, and convert to a `list` so that we get two new columns.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, as.list(coef(lm(Meas~len))), .(ID, Row, Col)]
```

Comment: This is an answer, but it is close to a code only answer. It would be good to explain the answer.

Comment: @Elin Added some text.